# Add network printer to Ubuntu Server via command line terminal

Tags: server, printing

I'm building an application that will need to print from the server. I have lots of printers on the network. All Ubuntu and Windows desktops can see them when browsing network printers. I want to print to one of the network printers using the default settings already setup for the printer on the network.

How do i add a network printer to `Ubuntu Server` (no GUI)?

Answer (score 5):

You can use CUPS with the following generic driver to install most of network printers built after 2009 as long as you have the printer IP address:

```
sudo apt install cups
sudo lpadmin -p printername -E -v ipp://192.168.1.111/ipp/print -m everywhere
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CUPS for that. 
Install it by typing `sudo apt install cups`
Here's their documentation on how to set up network printers:
https://www.cups.org/doc/network.html